# How to allow out of bounds index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I try to make the program so that the user can give input of the interger of the Month (e.g when user inputs number 4, The output should be April) and it will keep asking so long the user inputs a valid number (1 - 12). If user inputs an invalid number, the program should say "Invalid!", then terminate. However, my program cannot follow through the while-loop and immediately set the invalid number as an exception. What should I do to make the program says "Invalid!"? Thanks!

```
    String[] months = new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int i = 1;
    while(i < 13 && i > 0)
    {

        if(i > 12 && i < 1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Month?");
            i = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an infinite loop (i.e. `while(true){}`) and break it in case of `InputMismatchException` or the input integer out of the valid range (i.e. `1` to `12`).

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] months = new String[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" };
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i;
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Month?");
            try {
                i = input.nextInt();
                if (i >= 1 && i <= 12) {
                    System.out.println(months[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid");
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Month?10
Oktober
Month?1
January
Month?15
Invalid
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Month?12
December
Month?1
January
Month?abc
Invalid
```

### By using `java.time` API:

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Month?");
            try {
                Month month = Month.of(input.nextInt());
                // Change the locale as per your requirement e.g. Locale.ENGLISH
                System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.GERMAN));
            } catch (DateTimeException | InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Month?10
Oktober
Month?1
Januar
Month?15
Invalid
```

**Another sample run:**

```
Month?10
Oktober
Month?1
Januar
Month?Abc
Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the array bound is within 0 up to months.length-1, as array index starts from 0. Should avoid catching indexOutOfbounds, it indicates an issue with the code rather.

```
        i = input.nextInt();
        if(i-1 < 0 || i-1 >= months.length)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is always false, as a number cannot be > 12 and i < 1 at the same time. Use `i > 12 || i < 1` instead.

The exception happens when accessing the array, so you can first read the next number, then check it and only access the array if the number is valid.

The (minimally) corrected listing would be:

```java
        String[] months = new String[] {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"};
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        int i = 1;
        while(i < 13 && i > 0)
        {

            System.out.println("Month?");
            i = input.nextInt();
            if(i > 12 || i < 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Invalid!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 Options.

1. You wrap the array access into a try-catch block and catch the exception, then print "Invalid".
2. You stick to the following: First ask for the input, then check if the constraints are met, and only if the constraints are met, access the array. Then keep doing this in the loop until the constrains are not met anymore. (the better option)

Consider this example of option 2:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] months = new String[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "Oktober", "November", "December" };
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Month?");
    int i = input.nextInt();

    while (i < 13 && i > 0) {
        System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");
        System.out.println("Month?");
        i = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid!");
}
```

There is no need for the if-clause and the break, because the while loop does all the work.

Answer (score 0):

you should try something like this:------

(if u do not want to break loop)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] months = new String[] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August",
                "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" };
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Month?");
                int inputFromUser = input.nextInt();

                if (inputFromUser < 13 && inputFromUser > 0)

                {
                    System.out.println(months[inputFromUser - 1]);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid! input");
                    System.out.println("Do you want to come out from loop yes/no");
                    if (input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid! input , please provide the correct integer input");
                break;
            }
        }
        input.close();
    }
```

if you are ohk to break loop then try below logic:--

first check input using "if" then apply while loop.

Answer (score 0):

well you are using the same i variable for array indexing also that is why you are receiving exception  because before getting out of the while loop for entering invalid input the  `System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");` statement has to be executed so if the value in the array index `months[value]` is more than array size  you will receive exception for `ArrayIndexOutBoundsException` and also if index value is less than 0

to avoid that just add the `if(i>12 || i<1) break;` after the input statement `i = input.nextInt();`

```
System.out.println("Month?");
i = input.nextInt();
if(i>12 || i<1)
break;
System.out.println(months[i - 1] + "\n");
```

so after entering number greater than 12 or less than 1 the while loop will break

```
System.out.println("Invalid!");
```

will execute